# Magento 2: How to get individual review rating

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, review

I'm trying to get each individual review rating on a product, but currently I am only able to return the product's overall average rating.

Here is what I have so far to build my collection of reviews in my block file:

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  protected $reviewCollection;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewCollection,
    array $data = []
  ){
    $this->_reviewCollection = $reviewCollection;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }

  public function getReviews($product)
  {
    $reviews = $this->_reviewCollection->create()->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)->addEntityFilter('product',$product->getId())->setDateOrder();
    return $reviews;
  }
}
```

And then in my phtml file, I'm calling my block:

```
$reviews = $block->getReviews($product); // $product assigned earlier in code
if (count($reviews) > 0) {
  foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
    //get individual review summary here
  }
}
```

Not sure if I'm using the correct resource model in my block, maybe I need to build the collection of reviews differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out with the following:

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  protected $voteCollection;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\Option\Vote\CollectionFactory $voteCollection,
    array $data = []
  ){
    $this->_voteCollection= $voteCollection;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }

public function getReviewRating($reviewId)
  {
    $rating = $this->_voteCollection->create();
    $rating->addRatingInfo()->addOptionInfo()->addRatingOptions()->addFieldToFilter('review_id',$reviewId);
    return $rating->getData();
  }
}
```